# Extension Method overloading

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have this extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
     public static void ConsoleWriteLine(this object Value)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(Value);
     }
}
```

for integer values i have a little modification

```
public static void ConsoleWriteLine(this int Value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Integer: " + Value);
}
```

**my question is:** when i write `int x = 1; x.ConsoleWriteLine();` what makes the decision to take the second extension in this case? `int` is a  `object` aswell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what makes the decision to take the second extension in this case?

When the compiler has multiple valid methods to choose from, it uses a set of overload resolution rules to determine which method it should bind to.  The second extension method matches the calling signature *exactly*, so it is chosen.  Since any other type is *directly* convertible to `object`, the first extension would be chosen.  Other numeric types are *implicitly* convertible to `int`, but an implicit conversion is not "better" than a direct conversion to a parent class.

I believe the relevant spec here is 7.5.3.2:

> **7.5.3.2 Better function member**
>
> For the purposes of determining the better function member, a stripped-down argument list A is constructed containing just the argument expressions themselves in the order they appear in the original argument list.
>   Parameter lists for each of the candidate function members are constructed in the following way:
>
> ...
>
> Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions { E1, E2, ..., EN } and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter types { P1, P2, ..., PN } and { Q1, Q2, ..., QN }, MP is defined to be a better function member than MQ if
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion from EX to QX is not better than the implicit conversion from EX to PX, and

Since the "conversion" from `int` to `int` is "better" that the conversion from `int` to `object`, the `int` overload is chosen.

Note that this applies to *all* overloads, not *just* extension methods (although there are different rules for breaking the tie between extension and non-extension methods).

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When the compiler encounters a method invocation, it first looks for a
>   match in the type's instance methods. If no match is found, it will
>   search for any extension methods that are defined for the type, and
>   bind to the **first extension method that it finds**.

The compiler searches from bottom to top (that is, from child class to parent class, until it reaches the top of the class hierarchy), so in this case, the most specific method will always win.

Comment: What does bottom to top mean? All extensions here are in the same namespace.

Comment: @usr From bottom to top in the class hierarchy. That is, first it will search for extension methods on the type `System.Int32` and if none is matched, it will then proceed to search for the ones on `System.Object`

Comment: Don't think this is generally so. Shouldn't overload resolution look at all arguments? MSDN is often terribly vague. Here, nobody can tell what that sentence means.

Comment: "bottom to top" is confusing. You should say it searches for a method that matches the object's type.

Comment: @usr It works differently over inheritance: `[...] Inheritance can cause a confusing effect. When the compiler goes looking for instance method overloads, it considers the compile-time class of the "target" of the call, and looks at methods declared there. If it can't find anything suitable, it then looks at the parent class... then the grandparent class, etc. This means that if there are two methods at different levels of the hierarchy, the "deeper" one will be chosen first, even if it isn't a "better function member" for the call`

Comment: This was taken from [C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)

Comment: There's no instance method here. I don't think extensions are considered one.

Comment: @usr The same rule applies to extension methods

Comment: I still don't know what that sentence `first extension method that it finds` means. Clearly, this is false if taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
in this case:

```
public static class Extensions
{
 public static void ConsoleWriteLine(this object Value)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(Value);
 }
}
```

You're writing an extension method for an object. 
See:

```
this object Value
```

In your other extension method, you're writing an extension for an integer.

```
public static void ConsoleWriteLine(this int Value)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Integer: " + Value);
}
```

Because

```
this int Value
```

So, everytime you declare an Integer, this extension method will be called, because this is exactly a method for an integer and not for an object.